# В каких случая лучше использовать isset / !empty?

Tags: php

В каких случая лучше использовать  isset / !empty ?
По идее для обработки формы подойдёт только !empty, по скольку при регистрации данные поля быть заполнены, а вот для чего может быть полезен isset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем маны: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) и [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php).

`isset()` проверяет следующее - установлена ли вообще переменная?
Т.е. вернёт `true` даже если переменная равна пустой строке:
`$var = ''; if(isset($var)) print 'True';`

`empty()` проверяет следующее - не пуста ли переменная?
Т.е. вернёт `true` только если в переменной что-то есть:
`$var = ''; if(empty($var)) print 'True' else print 'Как нету?';`

Comment: Только с оговоркой на то, что isset реагирует на null, как на необъявленную переменную.

Answer (score 1):

> isset() проверяет следующее - установлена ли вообще переменная?

```
isset() проверяет инициализацию переменной
```